# Connect Postgres DB and Models (Django & Flask) in Docker containers

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

I have Docker Containers application with Flask and Django containers. It is possible share Database between Django container and Flask Container?

```
 django: &django
  ...
  depends_on:
  - postgres

 flask:
  ...
  ports:
    - "5090:5090"
  ...
  - postgres
  links:
  - postgres

 postgres:
   build:
   ...
   env_file:
  - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Models are in Django application. So, I need to do a Login in Flask Application using Postgres Database. The problem is, I only want to use the connection to Database, I do not need to do models in Flask.

I used Sqlalchemy method:

```
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    query = session.query(User)
    login = User.query.filter(username=form.username.data).first()
    if login is not None:
        print(login)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
   return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

And I tried with Panda method:

```
     if form.validate_on_submit():
    sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '{0}'".format(form.username.data)
    login = pd.read_sql_query(sql,SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
    if login is not None:
        print(login)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

But the error is the same in both cases, I need to do a relation, so, it is a Migration, in Flask.

```
   **sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "users"**
```

It is my database.py:

```
     ...
     SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (user, pwd, host, port, db)
     SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS')

     db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine))
     def init_db():
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to share the database between multiple containers. I wouldn't, but it's possible, nonetheless.

The error I see above seems to be that the user table doesn't have the name you'd expect. You can verify using some database gui or the `psql` cli tool. Unless you explicitly named it `users` it will be named using the `<app_name>_<model_name>` convention. If you're using the default django `User` model then the actual db table will be named `auth_user`.

Side note: you could definitely continue this way, but, if you have some time to invest on the problem: I'd highly suggest you look into OAUTH+OIDC, JWTs, and how to accomplish SSO using them.

Comment: Yes, to be honest, finally I leaved this way and I am trying to do it connecting Flask templates with DRF. Thanks for the advise.